# Set Maven '-Denvironment' with IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I can select the maven profile from IntelliJ 'Maven Projects' menu, however I am trying to figure out how can I set '-Denvironment=env' from IntelliJ IDE.

Where this is used for:

```
private static final String ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY_NAME = "environment";
```

Where "environment" would be `'dev'` or `'prod'`

Comment: What context are you wanting to set this in--is this for the Maven build? For executing the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences... > Maven > Runner

[image]

Or you can add `-Denvironment=env` to VM Options.

Answer (score 0):

To set the property for tests/main method running from IDE add

```
-Denvironment=env
```

to

```
Run -> Edit configurations -> (select your configuration in left menu) -> VM Options
```

You can save this to defaults (last item in the left menu) for all new configurations - very useful when running new tests.